# How to change navigation header button style based on a state property in React Native using React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm using react navigation in my RN app and trying to implement a form to submit some information. I'm using a button at the right header and want to style the button with different color to indicate whether the form is legal (e.g., white for a legal form and transparant for having important inputs left blank).

I use `this.state.submitDisabled` to indicate its legality and define the right header in `componentDidMount()` and pass the navigation param to the header to render in `navigationOptions`:

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({
  headerRight: (
    <MaterialHeaderButtons>
      <Item title="submit" iconName="check"
            color={this.state.submitDisabled ? colors.white_disabled : colors.white}
            onPress={() => {
              if (!this.state.submitDisabled) {
                this.postEvent();
              }
            }}/>
    </MaterialHeaderButtons>
  ),
});
```

However, the color change statement based on the value of `this.state.submitDisabled` did not work. I've checked its value, when `this.state.submitDisabled` is changed, the color of the button does not change. It seems that the color is determined when set as navigation params as above and will not change since then.

How can I achieve the effect of what I described?

Answer (score 2):

when ever you change value of state also change navigation param too.see example

```
export class Example extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        const showModal = get(navigation, 'state.params.showModal');

        return {
          headerTitle: <Header
            showModal={showModal}
            backIcon />,
          headerStyle: HeaderStyle,
          headerLeft: null,
        };
      };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      showModal: this.state.showModal,

    });
  }

  handleModal=(value)=>{
    this.setState({showModal:value});
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      showModal: this.state.showModal,
    });
}

render() {
return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation `this.state.submitDisabled` is not bound to the screen. Try the following:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  headerRight: (
    <MaterialHeaderButtons>
      <Item 
        title="submit" 
        iconName="check"
        color={navigation.getParam('submitDisabled') ? colors.white_disabled : colors.white}
        onPress={navigation.getParam('handlePress')}
      />
    </MaterialHeaderButtons>
  ),
})

componentWillMount() {
  this.props.navigation.setParams({
    submitDisabled: this.state.submitDisabled,
    handlePress: () => {
      if (!this.state.submitDisabled) {
        this.postEvent();
      }
    }
  });
}
```